# AWS Lambda and twitter streams

Tags: node.js, twitter, aws-lambda

I have Lambda function that runs every 5 mins and queries for new tweets for a particular user ID. This uses REST API now and works pretty well.

Using streaming API might have been a better way instead of running a nodeJs lambda function every 5 mins, right? Is there a way to use streaming API on Lambda nodeJs? Or any other code hosting service?

Answer (score 1):

Check the code in the following repo; It's connected to Twitter API stream and monitor some keywords and respond and insert to dynamoDB.

https://github.com/PBXDom/Twitter-Marketing-Nodejs

We use this code in our company for monitoring keywords in Twitter and find related leads.